# IE focus on form element in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

i have tried setTimeout, eval, try/catch, callback functions etc and nothing works reliably.  this has been driving me nuts for ages!  here is a [test case](http://alpha.sleekcode.net/)

Comment: What is your question? FWIW your test page focuses on the form input in both IE7 and FF3 for me.

Answer (score 1):

test page works for me